# Angular 2 CSS malfunction with Bootstrap v4 admin template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Running AngularJS 2.2.3 with Twitter Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.5. Here's what I'm getting:
[image: bad admin (thanks angular)]

Versus what I want:

[image: nice looking no angular]

Full code (with rendered output): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cbe4161acb3734c53c45c44db6db854b

EDIT: Full repo with the admin decomposed into different components: https://github.com/AlecTaylor/angular2-bootstrapv4-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing:

```
<link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also, you probably shouldn't use a CDN with Angular 2.

Add to package.json:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5",
```

Install with npm and reference from node modules:

```
npm i
```

reference:

You also probably want these as well:

```
npm i tether --save

<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, silly of me not to see that dashboard.css. Anyway it's not resolved yet, it still doesn't look right. Background is grey for one. On the other side of things, the `node_modules` directory doesn't seem to be mapped correctly. I've tried `<link href="{name}.css" rel="stylesheet">` of `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`, `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`, `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`, `bootstrap.min.css` and more. Also I've avoiding the JQuery dependency (Angular people don't like JQuery).